# Is the variational technique of quantum mechanics restricted to the energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, wavefunction, variational-principle

The variational method, as it pertains to quantum mechanics, is used to approximate the energies of a particular system. Is it possible to use the same variational method to approximate the eigenvalues of other observables?

Comment: Not sure if I completely understand your question.  The variational method is used to find the ground state energy of a system, not all energy states.  By definition, the ground state energy is the lowest energy state which allows a minimization approach.  You can apply this to any situation where you would want to find a minima I believe.

Comment: @GregPetersen I know what you're saying, but no you can actually use it cleverly to estimate higher excited states. http://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~gja/qp/qp8.pdf http://www.jetp.ac.ru/cgi-bin/dn/e_080_05_0783.pdf